# Oracle Materialized View Fast refresh on remote database

Tags: oracle11g

In my current db implementation, we do not have any data/tables in our db and gets all data from two other data sources. To do so we have created Materialized Views using dblinks to get data from these two other db sources. We use to COMPLETE refresh our Materialized Views daily at off business hours which takes approx 3 hours.

Both the sources databases are in Oracle. My Oracle version is 11.2.

We have got new business requirement that we have to now refresh our MVs with FAST method during business hours.

We initially thought to create MVs with FAST refresh on COMMIT. But later get to know over internet that we can not create ON COMMIT FAST refresh on remote dbs. Please correct me if i am wrong here.

Can we create MVs with FAST REFRESH ON DEMAND on remote dbs?

I understand that we also need to have MV logs on source tables. I am still investigating if the source is TABLES only or are they VIEWS as well.

Can we create MV logs on views at source?

This is the first time i am going to implement MV with FAST refresh option that too at remote dbs.

Request you to please help me with the steps with best possible way to implement MV with FAST refresh ON COMMIT/DEMAND on remote dbs.

Comment: You can fast refresh a materialized view over a database link.  You cannot do a refresh on commit.  The source tables would need appropriate materialized view logs.  You cannot define a materialized view log on a view.  If you are pulling from a view on the remote system, the definition of that view would need to meet all the restrictions to make the materialized view fast refreshable which are listed out in the Data Warehousing Guide for your version of Oracle.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Justin Cave for your valuable comments. I shall implement FAST refresh on demand.

Comment: @Justin Cave Please suggest if my following approach is fine for remote refresh. Suppose my remote db schema is remote1.  1) Then I shall be creating materialized view logs on all tables of this remote1 schema.   2) Replicating the these source tables by creating materialized views REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND WITH ROWID. These MVs will be a replica of the source table.   3) Using these FAST REFRESHED MVs I shall create another views to implement business logic.   4) I shall keep refreshing these MVs periodically agreed with business.   Request you to please suggest if this approach will work.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  But if it's going to be on topic here, we'd want to see what code you've tried, what error(s) you're getting, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Justin Cave for your response. And surly i shall keep you updated in case of any further issue.

Comment: Hello @Justin Cave, request you to please suggest where i am doing wrong in code as i am getting error "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" while creating materialized view with FAST refresh using db link. I have already created MV log on source table using command, "CREATE Materialized View Log ON  tbl_HB_SYSTEM;" and my create MV script is CREATE materialized view HB_SYSTEM 
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST 
ON DEMAND 
WITH primary KEY 
AS  
SELECT ID, DELETED_YN, SYS_NO FROM HB.tbl_HB_SYSTEM@HBLINK;

Comment: I have read in some forums that grant select privilege is required on MV Logs but i do not know the exact query/command to grant  privilege.

Comment: First, please edit your question to include code and errors.  Comments are intended to be transitory.  Second, my first guess is that the remote user that the database link is using doesn't have access to the `hb.tbl_hb_system` table on the remote server.

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave for your valuable comments. The issue is resolved after granting select to MV Log table using below query,   <br> GRANT SELECT ON MLOG$_<tableName> to USER;